# How to deserialize json to Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: c#

I have a class that looks similar to this

```
public class Demo
{
    [JsonProperty("variables")]
    [JsonExtensionData]
    IDictionary<string, object> Variables { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

My sample json looks like this

```
{
    "variables" : [
        {
            "a" : "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I post my data, Demo.Variables looks like this

```
{[variables, [
  {
    "a": "1"
  }
]]}
```

What I want is:

```
[{
  "a": "1"
}]
```

Comment: Does "[How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207731/1364007)" help?

Comment: @WaiHaLee No.  I want to be able to post my form data, and have the json property deserialize properly.  In the above question you mentioned, they are taking a json string and deserializing.

When I observe Demo.Variables I see [0] : {[variables, [
  {
    "a": "1"
  }
]]}

Rather than [0] "key" : "x", "value" : "1"

Answer (score 1):

You may need to look at your data a little different.

This JSON:

```
{
    "variables" : [
        {
            "a" : "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can be viewed as a collection of dictionaries like this:

```
public class Demo
{        
    public IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>> Variables { get; set; }
}
```

Then to get the output you requested:

```
[{
  "a": "1"
}]
```

Just serialize/deserialize like so:

```
public void Serialization()
{
    var dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Demo>(json);                       
    var postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto.Variables);
}
```

`postData` will then deserialize back to `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>>` just as indicated by the JSON `[{"a":"1"}]`